# Send payment requests

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, payment

Is there a plugin/solution or something else in Craft so that I can basically:

1) Create a payment request in the CP and send it to a specified email?

2) The email contains a link to a payment form which the user can fill in and pay (amount would have been passed via email)

3) When paid the status would be updated in Craft CP

I have seen the 'Charge' plugin (https://transition.topshelfcraft.com/software/craft/charge) which looks great but it doesn't look like its up to date.

Many thanks
Malcolm

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with Craft Commerce 3 Pro.

Create an email that would trigger on an 'Invoice' order status that you configure. (or any other name you want)

You would make the order in the Control Panel, then mark it as complete (which will set the the default status), then change the status to 'invoice' to trigger the email.

In the email template, link to a front-end payment form with the order `number` appended as a param like this `?number=78nc4y83fn4830f4nu304` Then in the payment form, pass in the `orderNumber` param based on the url `number` param.

This will make payment on the order and mark it as paid.

You can then see all orders with the status of 'invoice' in the CP, and see the ones that are paid or unpaid. You could move the order to a 'completed' status once you verify payment and ship the order.

Hope that helps.